# Query to return zero if nothing exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have a table with currency, paymenttype and invoiceamount. I have to write query to get currency, paymenttype and total invoiceamount made. This is pretty simple with `group by`. But actually I have three payment type 0, 1 ,2 and data in table is

```
Currency.  Paymenttype invoice amount
Aaa.        0.           100
Aaa.        1.           200
Aaa.        1.            50
Bbb.        0.           150
Bbb.        1.           100
Bbb.        2.           100
```

My query is Select currency, paymenttype, sum(invoiceamount) as total from table `group by` currency, paymenttype

Result

```
  Currency  paymenttype total
  Aaa.       0.           100
  Aaa.       1.           250
   Bbb.      0.           150
   Bbb.      1.           100
   Bbb.      2.           100
```

But what I want is as Aaa. Does not have 2 paymenttype is should also show a row with 0 value like below.

```
     Aaa.     2.     0
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the rows using a `cross join` and then join in the data you want:

```
select c.currency, pt.paymenttype,
       coalesce(sum(i.invoiceamount), 0) as total
from currency c cross join
     paymenttype pt left join
     invoice i
     on i.currency = c.currency and i.paymenttype = pt.paymenttype
group by c.currency, pt.paymenttype;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a table containing all the types.

Then you would simply do a `left join` on the payment_type_id an output the total, or 0 if nothing.

If you don't have a table with all the types, then you could simulate it but that would be a dirty fix :

```
select a.currency, b.paymenttype, coalesce(sum(a.invoiceamount), 0)
from (select 0 as paymenttype,
      union all select 1 as paymenttype,
      union all select 2 as paymenttype) b
left join yourTable a on a.paymenttype = b.paymenttype
group by a.currency, b.paymenttype;
```

Comment: This didn't worked for my data. Altough I figured out my query as  select aa.Currency,aa.PaymentType,sum(bb.amount) from (
select * from (select distinct paymenttype from payment) a cross join (select distinct currency from payment) c
) aa left join payment bb on aa.PaymentType = bb.PaymentType and aa.Currency = bb.Currency group by aa.PaymentType,aa.Currency
order by aa.Currency